# Remove braces around the comment

Tags: algorithmic

I would like to remove these braces around the comment I would like the comment to look like this `//AtLeast1T Leaf` as opposed to this `{//AtLeast1T Leaf}`  and I would like to keep using the `algorithmic` package and not switch to the `algorithmicx` one.

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
\newcommand{\proc}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\prop}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\plusplus}{{+}{+}}% Other options: 
\newcommand*\ita[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}% new
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Step 4-T Propagation}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \raggedright
    \STATE boolean modified=true
    \WHILE{modified==true}
    \STATE modified=false

    \FORALL{r in Requirements}   
    \FORALL{m in Methods}   

    \IF {m.trace[r]==E \AND  
        m.XCallees.isEmpty()
        \AND m.XCallers.AtLeast1T()
    }
    \STATE m.trace[r]=T\hfill\COMMENT{//AtLeast1T Leaf}
    \STATE modified=true    \ENDIF 
    \ENDFOR 
    \ENDFOR 

    \ENDWHILE
   \end{algorithmic}
   \label{step4}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possibilitys, depending on the way you want to write your comments in the algorithmn.

1. You can add

   ```
   \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{#1} % <===========================
   ```

   in your preanmble (before `\begin{document}`) and then use the code

   ```
   hfill\COMMENT{//AtLeast1T Leaf}
   ```

   including your wanted `//` in the text of the comment or
2. you can add

   ```
   \renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1} % <=========================
   ```

   including your wanted leading `//` for your comments in the preamble and use then

   ```
   \hfill\COMMENT{AtLeast1T Leaf} % <=============
   ```

   for your comments (no need to add the leading `//`).

Please see the following code showing both possibilities

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{#1} % <===========================
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Step 4-T Propagation}\label{step4} % <=========================
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \raggedright
  \STATE boolean modified=true
  \WHILE{modified==true}
    \STATE modified=false

    \FORALL{r in Requirements}   
    \FORALL{m in Methods}   

    \IF {m.trace[r]==E \AND  
        m.XCallees.isEmpty()
        \AND m.XCallers.AtLeast1T()
    }
      \STATE m.trace[r]=T\hfill\COMMENT{//AtLeast1T Leaf}
      \STATE modified=true
    \ENDIF 
    \ENDFOR 
    \ENDFOR 
  \ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1} % <=========================
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Step 4-Ta Propagation}\label{step4-1} % <======================
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \raggedright
  \STATE boolean modified=true
  \WHILE{modified==true}
    \STATE modified=false

    \FORALL{r in Requirements}   
    \FORALL{m in Methods}   

    \IF {m.trace[r]==E \AND  
        m.XCallees.isEmpty()
        \AND m.XCallers.AtLeast1T()
    }
      \STATE m.trace[r]=T\hfill\COMMENT{AtLeast1T Leaf} % <=============
      \STATE modified=true
    \ENDIF 
    \ENDFOR 
    \ENDFOR 
  \ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting algorithmns]

Please see that I moved your label from the bottom of your algorithm to the top of your algorithmn following the command `\caption`. The command `\label` has to follow `\caption` if you want correct refferences to the algorithm ...